# Finding Used Equipment

Tags: used-gear, equipment, upgrade, cheap

Hello folks.

I am looking to do some major upgrades on my kit, specifically my microphone. I have been looking for a used Sanken CS-3e. However, beyond eBay, my search hasn't been fruitful. I was wondering if you folks have tips on where to look for used equipment. I have heard plenty of stories about $2000 microphones being found for $1000. Granted, these are rare and specific events, but even a fraction of those savings would make the search worth it.

~Cheers

Comment: Well I found one for a reasonable price. Thanks for the tips. It opened my eyes to many new resources.

Comment: from jwsound boards
This Sanken CS3e is in mint condition, used on one job only.
I purchased it new at Trew Audio last month for $1545 plus 13% HST for a total of $1745.
The mic includes the foam windcover and Sanken case.

Offered at $1445 plus HST
No reasonable offer refused.

http://jwsoundgroup.net/index.php?/topic/8629-fs-mint-condition-sanken-cs3e/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

trew audio

professional sound services

gotham sound

location sound corp

coffey sound

all these companies have consignment pages on their websites.

granted, these are all located in the US, not sure where you are.

Comment: The US. My friend runs rentals at Professional Sound Services, so I'll ask him. Thanks! @greg

Comment: Trew Audio has a store in Toronto, FWIW.


Answer (score 4):

Although craigslist encourages people to buy and sell locally, you *can* search all of craigslist at once. There's [this](http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Search_Every_Craigslist_Site_at_Once) Wired article on how to set it up, but why do the heavy lifting, when [somebody else already has](http://www.searchallcraigs.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

jwsoundgroup.net

the buy/sell forum

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bblist.co.uk/

Baz's Bazaar carries alot of 2nd hand broadcast and has a massive audio section, it is a UK based list, but you might be able to get what you need shipped for a reasonable fee..

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Try Trew Audio as well.
Good luck finding a used Sanken CS-3e.  They can have mine when they pry it from my cold, dead fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Try posting on the forums that you are looking for one.